# Branch condition evaluates to a garbage value when dereferencing a pointer to a pointer

Tags: ios, c, pointers

I'm trying to clean up some issues from xcode's analyzer.  One I haven't found a solution to is the "Branch condition evaluates to a garbage value".  It's occurring in the following way:

```
int methodToCloseMyDatabase(sqlite3 **myDatabase, const char *callingFunctionName)
{
    if (myDatabase)
    {
        if (*myDatabase)  // The warning is thrown here
        {
           // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm *dying* to know if the Xcode analyzer throws the same fits with `if (myDatabase && *myDatabase)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error sounds to me as if CLang has analyzed your code and found that *myDatabase is not set to anything.

It could even be that the analyzer has found a possible code branch that does not set the value.

Comment: You are correct.  This is my first swing at analyzer, and I didn't realize that you could click and expand the issues, which leads you to other methods.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How did you set `myDatabase`? You probably forgot to initialize it correctly, so it points to arbitrary place in memory.